# How to incorporate modal popup in .net?

Tags: .net, modalpopupextender

I have an aspx page where there is a hyperlink control. On click of the hyperlink, I want to open another aspx page as a popup.Presently I am doing this by using javascript popup.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function openpopup()
{
  testwindow = window.open('ViewPlanner.aspx', "mywindow", 
 "menubar=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1,status=0,scrollbars=1,
  Width=980, height=600,left=10,top=50");
}
</script>
```

I have seen in many sites that modal windows are used with nice visual effects. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: This isn't really a .net question. Tag it with javascript to get some answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some jQuery plugins that do just that. Try searching google for "jquery modal" (excluding quotation marks) or "jquery modal dialog box" or "jquery modal window".

Hope this helps,
Guillaume